# COUNTIF in an Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, countif

Help,
I need to enter the following formula into an Excel spreadsheet.  If I enter this exact line of code into a macro I get a runtime error 1004 application-defined or object-defined error.  If I remove the “s around the “>500000000” and “>750000000” the macro error stops but then the COUNTIF in the spreadsheet gives an error.  Can anyone offer me  solution?  Thank you.

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(Row2, Col2 + 2).Formula = "=COUNTIF('Share Price Data Gain Trans'!U" & Row3 & ":U" & Row1 - 1 & ",">500000000")-COUNTIF('Share Price Data Gain Trans'!U" & Row3 & ":U" & Row1 - 1 & ",">750000000")"
```

Comment: I would store the formula in a string variable, debug.print it to the immediate window, copy it und insert into the excel cell manually. If it does not work you debug it in excel directly and adapt your vba code afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to double tho quotes around `>500000000` because quotes inside a string need to be doubled.

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(Row2, Col2 + 2).Formula = "=COUNTIF('Share Price Data Gain Trans'!U" & Row3 & ":U" & Row1 - 1 & ","">500000000"")-COUNTIF('Share Price Data Gain Trans'!U" & Row3 & ":U" & Row1 - 1 & ","">750000000"")"
```

Answer (score -1):

try a few more `&` and `"` or some extra `"`'s       `"" xxxx ""`

```
 & ","         &"          >500000000")-COUNTIF('Share Price Data Gain Trans'!U" & Row3 & ":U" & Row1 - 1 & ","         & "       >750000000")"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).